# Android - Spinner not able to select items

Tags: android, spinner

I have a problem with my spinner. I add the items on the spinner dinamically, from a edittext when a button it's pressed. The items are correctly shown when the spinner is pressed, but no selection can be done and there's no display on the spinner.

Here's the code:

```
    final ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, players); 
    final Spinner spinnerplayers = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerplayers);

    final ImageButton addbutton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
    final EditText editname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editname);
    final EditText editnum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editnum);
    addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            players.add(editname.getText().toString()+ " " + editnum.getText().toString());
            editname.setText("");
            editnum.setText("");
        }
    });

    spinnerplayers.setAdapter(adapter);

    final ImageButton removebutton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.removebutton);
    removebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //players.remove(spinnerplayers.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }
    });
```

If it's needed, the spinner xml is:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerplayers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Any idea about where's the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you managed to solve this? I am facing the same problem now..

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a custom adapter for this if you mean the clicklistenrs on your button are not working. You will apply listeners in getView method of the adapter.

Add you have to add OnItemSelectedListener.

```
 YOUR_SPINNER.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                            }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }

            });
```

The position gives you your item.

Comment: The listener on my button is working fine, it adds the text on the spinner and resets the edittexts. The problem is no selection can be done on the spinner, and so no display is shown there.

Comment: And btw i wont be using a spinner for this task i would use dialogs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it isn't just what I'm looking for. In fact I have already tried to add the listener on the spinner, but it keeps acting the same way.

Comment: you have to create your own layout xml file and set descendent focusability false. This will let you check your radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify:

```
adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
```

to refresh adapter showing each add/remove you make ?

Comment: I have just tried and there's no change in the behaviour. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you set it with android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item.

You can write your own Adapter class:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
spinner.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(CLASS.this, R.layout.spinner_layout, players));
```

Then it will look like the way you design in spinner_layout

Comment: My idea was to use android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, and the look is okay, the problem is it doesn't work as it's (or I) expected. It displays de radiobuttons on the right of the fields, but when pressed no selection is made, the radiobuttons do not turn to green and the selected item text is no displayed on the spinner. This differs from what I see from other spinners, which just work properly.